Why Bloom's Taxonomy revised while evaluating is more important than creating nowadays?
The thinking skill names of Bloom's Taxonomy is still unchanged semantically after revision in 2001, but the order has changed.
Where, the create is the highest order, swapping the place of evaluate after revised.
Nowdays, AI can generate (create), but still prone to error, like hallucination in Large Language Model. Thus, evaluation is the most important and should be in the highest order like original of Bloom's Taxonomy (1956).
This is make sense for me based on this requirement/dependency pattern:

To Understand, we must Remember.
To Apply, we must Understand.
To Analyze something, there must be something that has been applied.
To Create something, we need reference based on something that has been applied and analyzed.
Finally, to Evaluate something, there must be something that has been Created.

We can't evaluate for something that not exists.
So, why Create has higher order than Evaluate after revision, while the most energy drain of cognitive workload is Evaluate than Create, like evaluating the performance of generative (create) AI.


AI's 'creating' is more like regurgitating training sets in current versions, so why should evaluation be "most important" rather than fixing creation? And why should Bloom's taxonomy reflect AI issues in the first place when its stated mission is to help educating people?

Well, when you say fixing creation, it’s pretty much the same as evaluating. You’re assessing something to make it better, right? So it’s all about judgment and improvement.
If Bloom's Taxonomy is only limited about educating people, then AI as a subject can be an educator too for the people, not just humans. Therefore, AI (or generally educator) still needs to be evaluated.

No, it is not. By your own description, assessment/evaluation is subordinate and shouldn't be on top, the mission of education should be. Evaluation is certainly not that, creativity is a much better candidate. Doubly so, if AI is also only a subordinate tool. "Still needs to be" is moot because it applies to the entire pyramid, and evaluation is placed high as it is.

I don't think "evaluate" shouldn't be on top.

You may not think it, but your description implies it anyway. If you have a positive argument that evaluation is a goal in itself it is missing from your post or comments.

I added an argument about dependency pattern in edited post.

3 does not work, we can (and often do) analyze something before applying it. 4 can be replaced with "to evaluate something we must analyze it first" and 5 with "to create, we must master all of the above". In particular, we understand, analyze and evaluate what already exists before becoming ready to create something new. Creation from nothing is not for humans or AI. Generally, such 'dependency' patterns are too vague and pliable, and one can reshuffle the levels with ease. Bloom's ordering reflects a similarly vague idea of ranking by complexity of 'intellectual effort'.

What I mean with requirement/dependenc is, something "subject towards the object". For example, "To analyze something, there must be something that has been applied". So, here apply as object and analyze as subject. We can apply something without analyze, the application (an instance of apply) is self-independent without intervention of analysis, but we can't analyze something non-existent, what we analyze? Analyzing "understand" and "remember"? Apply, doesn't have to became physical concrete instance. The use of existing information from understand into idea is already an apply.

This is also applied between evaluate as subject and create as object.

In Generative AI with architecture Generative Adversarial Network, that consists of two parts. The Generator part is analog to creator, while the Discriminator part is analog to evaluator. Discriminator is subject towards the Generator, the evaluation performance of Discriminator is depending on what the Generator create,more,Discriminator is expecting the argument of creation instance. While, the Generator without Discriminator, can be think as self-indepedent object that create something freely, evaluate is optional.
